# How do you detect if a key is used twice in a JSON file with PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to created an error checking routine for an inbound JSON file in PHP.  The file that should produce an error is encoded as;

```
{
    "id" : 4,
    "id" : 3,
    "id" : 2,
    "id" : 1
}
```

How do I detect that "id" is used more than once instead of just letting the last value of id make it to the JSON object?  This is my overly simplistic code;

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
print_r($data);
```

it produces the result;

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [id
        ] => 1
    )
```

Other than testing the string with substr_count() for multiple instances of '`"id"`' is there a better (more efficient?) way to accomplish this task?

Comment: You might need a different JSON parser... I'm not sure that the built-in PHP parser will support duplicate keys.

Comment: With the default processing in place the json_decode() function has the follow on definitions of the same key overwrite the previous ones, as shown above.  I'm trying to have the duplicate throw an exception that I can catch and throw back to the user.  I think I can do it with substr_count() but I was wondering if there is a better or more efficient way.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is generating JSON with duplicate keys anyway?  I know the spec allows it, but have never seen anything actually generate such JSON.

Comment: In truth, I'm the one generating the invalid JSON thru the use of the application Postman.  I created this as a test case with the expectation that it would fail with sort sort of format error or duplicate key error.  Much to my surprise it just kept overwriting the original value with the newer value.

Comment: That's because it's not an error to have JSON with duplicate keys.  This isn't a problem I'd worry about solving unless you have some specific reason to do so.